# how to change mapper memory requirement in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In a map-reduce job, i got the error "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space". Since I get this error in a mapper function; I thought that when I lower the input size to the mapper I will have no more error, so I changed the mapred.max.split.size to a much more lower value.

Then, I started the job again and i saw that "number of mapper tasks to be executed" has increased, so i thought that lowering mapred.max.split.size was a good idea: more mappers with lower memory requirements.

BUT, I got the "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error again, again and again.

It seems that, i did not understand how hadoop works.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share you mapper code?

Comment: I am using mahout, seq2sparse function.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the **child heap size** with: `mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx3000m`, (in newer APIs you can be more specific with `mapreduce.map.java.opts`). You could also tune your node by choosing how many map and reduce tasks can be run in parallel. This can be controlled by the **number of map** and reduce **slots** available in a Tasktracker for example:

`mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum=7`
`mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum=3`

There are **more options**: `mapred.cluster.map.memory.mb=300` and `mapred.job.map.memory.mb=600` but I don't think you will need them for now.

Comment: I already modified mapred.child.java.opts and mapred.tasktracker.*.tasks.maximum, but no solution. I think, the real reason is; I still did not understand how hadoop works. For example; what is the relation between slot and task? For example; what is the meaning of "A job can ask for multiple slots for a single map task"?

Comment: A tasktracker is running map and reduces tasks. A map task is a map function being called on a single input split. A tasktracker runs on a slave instance (as opposed to the jobtracker = master). The tasktracker can create a number of jvms to process tasks, which is limited by the slots parameters. I think you have to provide us with extra information about your map function for us to understand why it is running out of memory